# Could this be considered a security vulnerability?

Tags: javascript, security

I discovered some javascript in a site that didn't sanitize external data (`siteName`), but it's used in such a way that I think does not represent a problem.  Certainly, the best thing to do would be to filter it so that only expected values could interact with code and there would be no worry about unexpected input.  But, how much damage could be inflicted in the current setup?

```
var branding = {
    'website1.com' : {
        color: 'red'
    },
    'website2.com' : {
        color: 'blue'
    }
};

var siteName = document.referrer.split('/')[2];

var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".some-class-name");

for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
    myElements[i].style.color = branding[siteName]['color'];
}
```

Comment: You cannot really do anything with it.

Comment: everything client side can't be considered secure in any way

Comment: Why would that be a security issue? Are you saying the list of sites should not be public, or...? There *is* a bug in that if the referrer site isn't in the list it will result in a runtime exception - is that the missing sanitisation that you're talking about?

Comment: There are no security vulnerabilities in that code. Vulnerabilities would only exist if the code can execute arbitrary JavaScript that comes from untrusted sources.

Comment: @nnnnnn re: sanitization, I was thinking along the lines of injection; could a malicious function be passed or something like that.  Good point about the runtime exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is poorly conceived, but I don't think it's exploitable.

- `document.referrer.split('/')[2]` extracts the hostname of the referrer. An attacker might have control over the hostname, but only to a limited degree; they can't put anything into that field that they can't register or set up as a domain name.
- `branding[siteName]` could be made to do some interesting things if `siteName` is the name of an internal property on Object, like `__proto__`, or a method name, like `hasOwnProperty`. However, none of these properties would have been valid as Internet hostnames, as none of them have periods in them. `__proto__` contains underscores, which aren't even valid in hostnames!
- If `siteName` were not constrained, the following `['color']` still limits this code. Functions (like `hasOwnProperty`) wouldn't have a `color` property; nor would the Object prototype, so this looks like a dead end.
- Even if we assume that a weird value like a function *somehow* got into the result, assigning a value like that to `.style.color` wouldn't do anything weird.

The potential for a vulnerability could easily be avoided, though:

```
var siteName = document.referrer.split('/')[2];

if (branding.hasOwnProperty(siteName)) {
    ... everything else ...
}
```

`Object.hasOwnProperty` is false for method names and "weird" properties like `__proto__`; it's only true for properties that have been explicitly declared on an object. This would limit the following code to only running for the intended site names.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `.hasOwnProperty()`. Would that require that `branding` be constructed differently?  As I understand it, `branding` is an associative array, not an object.

Comment: Nope, no other changes required. Javascript objects _are_ associative arrays -- `{…}` defines an object.